# How to override nested blocks in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

If I define a block inside a block in a Jinja template, and extend it, How do I reference the nested block in the child template?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You reference the nested block the same way you reference any block, e.g., given

```
{% block outer_block %} 
  Outer things
  {% block inner_block %}
    Inner things
  {% endblock %}
  More outer things
{% endblock %}
```

You'd override `inner_block` with

```
{% block inner_block %} 
   customized inner content
{% endblock %}
```

Can you clarify what problem you're encountering?  Or are you running into scoping issues, e.g., http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#block-nesting-and-scope ?